# Monero RPC - Failed to parse transaction from daemon

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-failed

I am running the latest version of `monerod` and `monero-wallet-rpc` on my Ubuntu 16 machine. My `monerod` daemon is fully synced and seems to be working fine. I am using `monero-wallet-rpc` to run a faucet service for Monero and require my users to be able to withdraw from their wallets.

When I run the wallet RPC, I am getting a large amount of warnings and error messages.

`E Failed to parse transaction from blob`

`W Failed to parse transaction from daemon`

`E Invalid tx data`

Here is my RPC command:

`./monero-wallet-rpc --rpc-bind-port 28083 --wallet-file monerowallet --password THISISWHERETHEPASSWORDIS --disable-rpc-login`

And how I run `monerod`

`./monerod`

What could be the cause of these errors?

Comment: Can you also paste your daemon command line please?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Looks like you are on an incorrect chain. You definitely running the latest version and definitely fully synced? You can check your daemons height (status command) against xmrchain.net.

Comment: The height is correct, I'm definitely on the right chain

Comment: @Barney can you specify *when* you get those errors please?